# Hartshorne ex II $2.16$ part b.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $X$ be a scheme, let $f \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$, and define $X_f$ to be the subset of points $x \in X$ such that the stalk $f_x$ of $f$ at $x$ is not contained in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x$ of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_x$. Assume that $X$ is quasi-compact. Let $A = \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ and let $a \in A$ be an element whose restriction to $X_f$ is $0$. Show that for some $n > 0$, $f^na = 0$.

I'm trying to understand this problem by breaking it to pieces, but I have some trouble with some of the concepts.

$X$ being quasi-compact gives us that we can take any cover $\{U_i\}_i$ for $X$ and reduce it to a finite $\{U_n\}_n$ subcover.

$A$ is denoting the global sections of $X$ here and $a$ is now one of such sections. The set $X_f = \{x \in X \mid f_x \notin \mathfrak{m}_x \}$ is quite similar to a distinguished open set $D(f)$, but still in some way different.

Lastly the condition $f^na = 0$ reminds me about $f$ being in some kind of a nilradical, but I'm not sure which one. I don't think it's in $ \operatorname{nil}(A)$ since we have this coefficient of $a$.

Could someone help me understand the problem better and what is being asked here? I think my issue is not understanding $X_f$ as it's not really an distinguished open set.

Comment: Are you able to do the exercise when $X = \mathrm{spec}\ A$ is affine ?

Comment: I haven't tried it in that way. What I tried is to take a cover for $X$ with affine opens. How does the exercise change if we assume $X$ is affine itself? @vanxoo

Comment: It will help you understand the condition $f^na=0$, and then you will be able to apply it to each part of your affine cover, and then "glue" the results

Comment: So if we take $\{U_i\}$ to be an affine cover and reduce it to a finite subcover we can restric the global sections $f$ and $a$ to $f_i$ and $a_i$ on $U_i$ and have that $U_i \cap X_f = D(f_i)$. Can we proceed from here? @vanxoo

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how to do it ! Now you need to translate the condition that $a_i$ vanishes on $D(f_i)$ into algebra, and see what is means

Comment: Well $D(f_i) = \{ \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec} B_i \mid f_i \notin \mathfrak{p} \}$ so if $a_i$ vanishes on $D(f_i)$ I think it means that $a_i(\mathfrak{p}) = 0$ for any $\mathfrak{p} \in D(f_i)$, but I'm still lost at this $f^n a = 0$ condition. @vanxoo

Comment: Can you formulate all of this is terms of the localization $A_{f_i}$ ?

Comment: I know that $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f_i)) = A_{f_i}$, but we are looking at $D(f_i)$ here instead of the sections of $D(f_i)$. Or is it that $a_i \in \mathcal{O}_X(D(f_i)) = A_{f_i}$? @vanxoo

Comment: I should have said $(B_i)_{f_i}$ rather than $A_{f_i}$. $a_i$ is in $B_i$ ; but what is its image in $(B_i)_{f_i}$ ? To answer this you need to see what are the prime ideals of $(B_i)_{f_i}$.

Comment: Do you mean that $a_i \in \mathcal{O}_{X|U_i}(D(f_i)) = (B_i)_{f_i}$? The prime ideals of $(B_i)_{f_i}$ correspond to the prime ideals of $B_i$ containing $f_i$ if I remember correctly. @vanxoo

Comment: Crucially, they are the prime ideals of $B_i$ _not_ containing $f_i$ ;)

Comment: Oh yeah my bad... How does this tie in with $f^na = 0$? Do we get some local condition for this first? @vanxoo

Comment: I'm thinking we don't need this prime condition as $a_i = 0$ in $(B_i)_{f_i}$ if there exists $f_i^{r_i}$ such that $f^{r_i}_ia_i = 0$.

Comment: @KReiser The linked one seems to be a different problem?

Comment: Oops! That'll teach me to close questions before having my morning coffe. My apologies!